# Set status Approved to one row and Rejected to others row at the same time

Tags: mysql

What I am going to do here is to update the status from Pending to the status of "Approved" or "Rejected" based on the posted value.

The scenario is there is one request send to some admins. For example this request is sent to 5 Admin.

IF ONLY one of these 5 admin update the status of the user request from Pending to "Approved", then this request for others Admin will be rejected automatically.

NOT Vice-versa, if one admin "Rejected" this request, it means there would be still four admins who may accept the request.

```
   $result = $mysqli->query ("UPDATE infistall_location_stock_collect_list 
                              SET status = '$status'
                              WHERE location_id = '$locationed'
                              AND reference_no = '$reference_no'");
```

So the point is, I want to check what Status is sent from the Admin. Is it Rejected? Or Is it Approved.

IF the status from query above is Approved, then another query will be REJECTED

```
   $result = $mysqli->query ("UPDATE infistall_location_stock_collect_list 
                              SET status = 'REJECTED'
                              WHERE location_id <> '$locationed'
                              AND reference_no = '$reference_no'");

   //Pay attention to location_id => which admin it is.
```

Only there are 3 status: Pending, Approved, Rejected.

Pending is the default status when the user send the request.

Comment: So, what is the goal do you want?

Comment: So the point is, I want to check what Status is sent from the Admin. Is it Rejected? Or Is it Approved.

IF the status from query above is Approved, then another query will be REJECTED.

Comment: Oh,, you should run those two queries. The set "REJECTED" query run after the confirmation of admin. I think it would be hard to make it a single query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need an `IF` statement:

```
   $update = $mysqli->query ("UPDATE infistall_location_stock_collect_list 
                              SET status = '$status'
                              WHERE location_id = '$locationed'
                              AND reference_no = '$reference_no'");
if ($status == "APPROVED"){
   $update_other = $mysqli->query ("UPDATE infistall_location_stock_collect_list 
                              SET status = 'REJECTED'
                              WHERE location_id <> '$locationed'
                              AND reference_no = '$reference_no'");

}
```

Comment: I just was always afraid if this can be done with that simple. Thanks.